# Creating update trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to delete rows from Table A with row ids same as those rowId's which were updated in Table B. so, I am assuming I need to create an after update trigger.

For example: if `time` column in rows with row ID `1`, `2`, `3` was updated of Table B, then Table A should delete rows with row ID 1, 2 and 3.

This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[Patients] 
FOR UPDATE
AS  
    DECLARE @row INT

    SELECT @row = (SELECT RowId FROM Inserted)

    IF UPDATE (ModifiedAt)
       DELETE FROM dbo.CACHE 
       WHERE Cache.RowId = @row
GO
```

However, if there was a batch update, trigger would be fired only once. How do I delete all rows from `dbo.Cache` with rowid same as those updated in `dbo.Patients` ?

Comment: Some sample would be useful. To. Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inserted` is a table that contains all the updates; you can just use it as such.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[Patients]
FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN;

    IF UPDATE([ModifiedAt])
        DELETE dbo.Cache WHERE RowID IN (SELECT RowID FROM inserted)
END
```

Note that I'm using `SET NOCOUNT ON` to ensure the trigger doesn't return any extra result and a `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()` check to prevent problems with recursion (not a problem for a single trigger, but a good idea in general).

Comment: Thank you. That looks nice. However I have a quick query. When do values from inserted table get flushed ? I am asking this this I am concerned about unintended deletions. Are values populated for every trigger and then removed from inserted right after trigger is done whatever it was supposed to do?

Comment: The rows in `inserted` exist only for as long as the trigger is executing. If a trigger manages to trigger itself or another trigger (a scenario which is very much not recommended as it gets very hard to control very quickly) then those triggers get new `inserted` tables that reflect those inserts, but for normal uses, you can consider it a temp table that's gone when your trigger finishes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the trigger in a set-based way, such as;

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[Patients] FOR UPDATE
AS  

   if update(ModifiedAt)
      delete c from dbo.CACHE c INNER JOIN inserted i on i.RowId = c.RowId

GO
```

Comment: It gives an error that says inccorrect syntax near the keyword INNER

Comment: @Simran Sorry - just fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DELETE ... FROM`:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Cache FROM dbo.Cache JOIN inserted I ON I.RowId=Cache.id
```